# Google drive API publish document and get published link

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, google-drive-api

If I make a document in Google drive and type some text, I can later go to file => Publish to the Web and get a link to a [public webpage-style of the google doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vS7dClacVC01OqLdrxu2lCuWNc39BFgin3wxvaM49SjkiAxMRV_k8ZY4uJar8KZcXWhUXMVefGsmQnM/pub), along with an embed link.

This is how its done manually. How can I do this automatically with a [Node.JS server](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs) script (for example, using a [Service Account](http://isd-soft.com/tech_blog/accessing-google-apis-using-service-account-node-js/)) using the [Goolgle Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/export)? I couldn't find anything about this particular thing in their docs, is this possible? DO I need to make a google script instead? Is it even possible with that?

Comment: I think that the Google Document can be published to Web using Drive API with Node.js. When you want a sample script, can I ask you about your situation? 1. Do you want to achieve this using [googleapis with Node.js](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/nodejs)? 2. Have you already been able to use Drive API? 3. When the service account is used and when the Google Document is in you Google Drive, at first, it is required to share the file with the service account. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes I'm able to create a service acccount and share files etc. but I want the service account to be able to craeate a new file, publish it to web, and send  the public URL somewhere

Comment: Thank you for replying. You have already had the service account. I could understand like this. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I have more 3 questions. 1. Do you want to achieve this using googleapis with Node.js? 2. What is `a new file` of `I want the service account to be able to create a new file, publish it to web, and send the public URL somewhere`? In the current stage, only Google Docs (Spreadsheet, Document and Slides) can be published to the web. How about this? 3. Have you already been able to use Drive API? For example, can you run Quickstart in your question?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes I can run the quick start, I want to be able to create a new document, and accomplish the same, with the API, as I would be able to accomplish by clicking on "File" and then "Public to Web" and then copying the link. Do you understand?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, you have already been able to create new Google Document and edit it using Node.js. In your question, you want to publish the Google Document to the web using googleapis with Node.js and retrieve the published URL. In this case, you want to use the service account. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Tanaike yep correct-or-entio

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You want to publish the Google Document to web using googleapis with Node.js.
- You want to retrieve the published URL.
- You want to achieve this using the service account.
- You have already had the service account and been able to use Drive API.

From your question and replying comments, I could understand like this. If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Usage:

In order to use the following sample script, please do the following flow.

1. Prepare a Google Document.

   - In this case, as a test case, please create new Google Document to your Google Drive.
2. Share the created Google Document with the email of the service account as the writer.
3. Retrieve the file ID of the Google Document.
4. Set the variables to the following sample script.
5. Run the script.

   - In this case, "Revisions: update" of Drive API is used.

By this, the Google Document is published to the web and you can see the published URL at the console.

#### Sample script:

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");

// Please set the email and private key of service account.
const auth = new google.auth.JWT(
  "### email of service account ###",
  null,
  "### private key of service account ###" ,
  ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
);
const fileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID.

const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
const body = {
  resource: {
    published: true,
    publishedOutsideDomain: true,
    publishAuto: true
  },
  fileId: fileId,
  revisionId: 1
};
drive.revisions.update(body, err => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`https://docs.google.com/document/d/${fileId}/pub`);
});
```

- Please set the private key like `"-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n###\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"`.

### Note:

- The published URL is `https://docs.google.com/document/d/${fileId}/pub`. In this case, the file ID is used. Because unfortunately, in the current stage, the URL like `https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-###/pubhtml` cannot be retrieved by Google API.

### Reference:

- [Revisions: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions/update)